# android studio how to support multiple screen layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

In my application I am working with static and dynamic layouts.For static layout I have just added files into res/layout. and for dynamic I am converting dp to px that is.

```
 public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px=Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics));
    return px;
```

}

These solutions are not working with all densities and looks different in all sizes.

I have found this solution while searching. i.e. add all layouts inside following folders.
res/layout– The default image folder,
res/layout-sw200dp,
res/layout-sw600dp,
res/layout-sw800dp.

Is there any another solution for static and dynamic layout creation

Comment: The solution you find while surfing of adding multiple layout folders inside res folder is the best solutions that works.

Comment: ok and what do I do with dp to px method.

Comment: i donot know exactly why you want to convert dpToPx , by default you create a dynamic layout is using dp and it is fine to use it.

Comment: I am creating popup and some layouts at runtime